# Batch file to only copy new files from source to destination

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to create a batch file that copies only new files to another folder.  I have .png files that come in through FTP at various times throughout the day.  So I am looking for a .bat that I can run once a day that will only copy the new .png files and place them in the destination folder.

However, the destination folder is always empty.  This is because the software I use auto fetches the .png files for processing.  I have been manually moving these .png files over everyday.

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking, here. Can you perhaps [edit] your question and provide an example flow from start to finish?

Comment: Why don't you use Robocopy?

Comment: xcopy C:\Test1\ C:\Test2\ /d /s /r /y     This is what i have so far, but it only if the same files are in the destination folder.

Answer (score 2):

The `xcopy` utility will do what you want:

```
xcopy /s /d {source dir}\ {target dir}\
```

or:

```
xcopy /s /d {source dir}\*.PNG {target dir}\
```

The first example copies all files, while the second copies only `.PNG` files.

Omit `/s` if you want to copy a single directory, not whole tree.

Comment: Is there a way to only copy new .png files?  such as only copy the new .png files for each new day.

Comment: That's precisely what the commands do: `/d` specifies to copy only new and updated files. If you want to copy each day's files to a separate directory, you will need to add a date to the `/d` (see `xcopy /?`).